# Schedule clause in OpenMP

Tags: openmp

I have a piece of code (which is part of an application) that I'm trying to optimize using OpenMP, am trying out various scheduling policies. In my case, I noticed that the `schedule(RUNTIME)` clause has an edge over others (I am not specifying a chunk_size). I've two questions:

1. When I do not specify chunk_size, is there a difference between `schedule(DYNAMIC)` and `schedule(GUIDED)`?
2. How does OpenMP determine the default implementation-specific scheduling that is stored in the `OMP_SCHEDULE` variable?

I learned that if no scheduling scheme is specified, then by default `schedule(STATIC)` is used. So if I don't modify the `OMP_SCHEDULE` variable, and use `schedule(RUNTIME)` in my program, would the scheduling scheme be `schedule(STATIC)` all the times or does OpenMP have some intelligent way to dynamically devise the schedule strategy and change it from time to time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, if you do not specify a chunk size then DYNAMIC will make the size of all chunks 1.  But GUIDED will make the minimum chunk size 1 but other chunk sizes will be implementation dependent.  Perhaps you could figure out your situation by running some experiments or reading the documentation.
2. As I understand the situation: if the environment variable OMP_SCHEDULE is not set then the runtime schedule is implementation dependent.  I think it would be very odd if the same schedule was not chosen for each execution of the program.  I do not believe that OpenMP, which is a set of compile-time directives, has any way to understand the run-time performance of your program and to choose a schedule based on such information.

Comment: Thanks Mark. In my tests, DYNAMIC was some points above GUIDED, and RUNTIME was the winner all the times.

Comment: I got this answer from a kind user at the OpenMP forum - http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=880

Comment: OpenMP, which is a set of compile-time directives, could generate code that monitors performance and adjusts schedule based on that information. I'm not saying it currently does, but it can't be ruled out simply because it's a set of compile-time directives.